# mysql/mariadb - LEFT JOIN aggregate not returning all values

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

First up, I don't know how to word this question so if there's any better terminology or phrasing, feel free to edit.

---

So here's my schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca46c1/2

```
CREATE TABLE map
  (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  );

CREATE TABLE vote_map
  (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    map_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    score ENUM("-1", "0", "1")
  );

 CREATE VIEW view_vote_map_rank AS
  SELECT
    map.id AS map_id,
    COALESCE( SUM(CAST(CAST(score AS char) AS SIGNED)), 0) AS score
  FROM vote_map
  RIGHT JOIN
    map ON map.id = vote_map.map_id
  GROUP BY map_id;


INSERT INTO map (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO map (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO map (id) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO map (id) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO map (id) VALUES (5);

INSERT INTO vote_map (user_id, map_id, score) VALUES (1, 1, '1');
INSERT INTO vote_map (user_id, map_id, score) VALUES (2, 2, '1');

SELECT * FROM map;
SELECT * FROM view_vote_map_rank;
```

The results I'm getting are

```
map_id  score
3   0
1   1
2   1
```

However this is incomplete. I was also expecting id `4` and `5` there as well, with a score of `0` too. I'm not sure why it's stopping after the first `0`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view, you could use the following:

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  sum(IF(b.score IS NULL,0,b.score)) as `score`
FROM map a
LEFT JOIN vote_map b
ON a.id = b.map_id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Simpler and in your SQL Fiddle, it seems to return the correct results

Comment: Since my `score` is an enum, that won't work. Will need to edit to `CAST(CAST(b.score AS char) AS SIGNED)`. Otherwise seems to work.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. After looking at your query, I think the problem is you are doing a right join instead of a left join.

Comment: My `RIGHT JOIN` is equal to your `LEFT JOIN`, since our table order is swapped around.

Comment: Not equal -- the GROUP BY is hitting a different column.